# How to test compression algorithms on MATLAB Data?

Tags: matlab, compression, image-compression

I have a variable A which is 581*581 single and when I use the command imshow(mat2gray(A)) I see a biological cell that I am supposed to. Let's say I am conducting research where I want to test out how the JPEG algorithm (or some other, for the matter of compression) performs on this data. How do I test this out? When I read research papers, they are able to test various compression algorithms out there on their data. I want to be able to know the achieved compression ratio, time complexity, and other details for that matter to compare the performances of different compression algorithms.

Comment: you can start with whos and cputime

Comment: but how do I get those algorithms? (like JPEG)

Comment: [Digital Image Processing Using MATLAB](https://www.amazon.com/Digital-Image-Processing-Using-MATLAB/dp/0982085400)

Comment: Thanks for the help.
The book mentions that the JPEG algorithm they provided only approximates the baseline process and that the full algorithm is beyond the book's scope.
Do you know how I can find the full algorithm and use it?  Should I look for books on the topic?

Comment: JPEG is a format specification rather than an algorithm. Better algorithms appears [now](https://arxiv.org/abs/1612.08712v2) an [then](https://arxiv.org/abs/1708.00838).

Comment: So, JPEG, JPEG2000, JPEG-LS, etc are all format specifications? Then, why do so many research papers I read refer to them as common standards? I read that the author has come up with some new algorithm. Then, they compare their algorithm with other algorithms already out there such as the ones I mentioned. I suppose they don't write the code for each one themselves, apart from their own. So, where is the "source" one should refer to?